# Adjust tabs to have same height as the tallest tab in Materialize.css

Tags: css, tabs, materialize

When using tabs in Materialize CSS, each tab is as tall as its content.

Info tab
[image: Info tab]

Feedback tab
[image: Feedback tab]

What do I do to make all tabs as tall as the tallest tab?

I know I can set a minimum height for the divs, but what I am really interested is to know if I can do it with a materialize helper or a materialize class.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row card hoverable">
        <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Info</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Feedback</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">QA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="test1" class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h5>Location</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    <p>consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                    <p>Cras vestibulum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col push-s1">
                    <h5>Available Timings</h5>
                    <p>Mon: 8AM - 9PM</p>
                    <p>Tue: 8AM - 9PM</p>
                    <p>Thu: 8AM - 9PM</p>
                    <p>Sat: 10AM - 2PM</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <strong>ID:</strong> ABBS1243xA
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" class="col s12">
            <ul>
                <li>Sorry, no feedback available at this time.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/animeshb/pen/prLWqb/).

Comment: Not possible trough css nor materialize itself. However a simple jquery script should do the trick I can provide you with one if needed.

Comment: Oh, sure that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this in your java-script

```
$(".tabs-content").css('height','1000px');
```

"tabs-content" is generated by materialize java script. Here I address that class using my java-script. 1000px can vary according to your need.

Hope this helps.